# Asciidoctor This page can't be displayed error

Tags: java, maven, asciidoctor

I am trying to incorporate `asciidoctor`in my parent project. For some reason the page is not rendering properly. The site generation is successful and even the link is there but it doesn't display the content of the page.

pom.xml

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.5</version>
                </dependency>
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctorj</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

site.xml

```
<menu name="Asciidoctor" >
        <item href="hello.html" name=" Asciidoctor Report" />
</menu>
```

directory for hello.adoc

[image]

So when I click on the link, it says the page can't be displayed. Do I need to configure something since it is not rendering the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple. It may not be a best solution because of the fact that the existing pom configuration should have worked based on my need but it didn't. I changed my packaging and instead of creating the ascii folder inside the resources folder I put it one step ahead. I think by default Asciidoctor looks under site and ascii folder foe the .adoc file extension. After doing that hello.html started rendering properly.

Comment: Did yo have to specify the folder structure inside the pom as part of configuration?

Comment: It looks like you need to specify the path in the pom if you create the .adoc file somewhere else apart from the standard asciidoctor folder structure. In my case I am putting it in ascii folder under site directory which is recognized by the asciidoctor by default.